# Prove or disprove a converse to l'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Assume that:

1)
$$ \lim_{x\to c}f(x) = \lim_{x\to c}g(x) = 0, $$
where $c$ is a **finite** real number contained in an interval $I=(a,b)$ (which means that we have excluded the situation that $c=\pm\infty$);

2. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable on the interval $I$ except possibly at the point $c$ above;
3. $$\lim_{x\to c}f^{'}(x) = \lim_{x\to c}g^{'}(x) = 0;$$
4. $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ exits and is equal to $L$.

Then prove or disprove: $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f^{'}(x)}{g^{'}(x)}$ exits and is equal to $L$.

It's seems that most counterexamples I have found are under one of the following two circumstances:

1)$c=\pm\infty$,  and

2)$c\neq\pm\infty$ but either $\lim_{x\to c}f^{'}(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to c}g^{'}(x)$ is allowed to be nonzero,

but it seems harder to find a counterexample given that **both circumstances above are excluded**. Can anyone be so kind to help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you specify your example for $c=+\infty$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Let $f(x) = x+sinx$ and $g(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f^{'}(x)}{g^{'}(x)}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: But in this case $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=+\infty$ right ?

Comment: @P.Quinton You're right. I made a mistake, but I do find out this counterexample for $c\neq\infty$ but both $\lim_{x\to c}f^{'}(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g^{'}(x)$ is nonzero: let $f(x) = x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x) = x$ and $c = 0$.

Comment: Just a note — “a **finite** real number” is redundant, since real numbers by definition are finite — ±∞ are not real numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take

$$
f(x)=x^3\sin\frac 1x,\qquad  g(x)=x^2,\qquad c=0.
$$

Then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&=0,\\[12pt]
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)&=0\\[12pt]
\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} g'(x)&=0\\[12pt]
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}&\quad\text{does not exist}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. It makes me seem stupid that I have noticed the counterexample that $f(x) = x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x}$, $g(x) = x$ and $c = 0$ but still couldn't modify it in order to satisfy the conditions given.